# How should a devotee respond to bigotry towards his or her ishta?

Tags: identification-request, bhakti

Following some attacks on certain deities on this site, a question has arisen on my mind on how such statements should be responded by devotees.

For example, if a person comes to a devotee and insults his or her deity, how should a true devotee react?

I know its natural for devotees to feel offended and angered by such statements but at the same time, as we know the Self is Brahman in Advaita philosophy and God resides as the "antaryami" in the hearts of all living beings in Vishishtadvaita philosophy (and also knowing that such statements arise mainly due to contact of the Self with Prakriti), what would a true devotee react like? What have the scriptures said regarding this?

Comment: In one word simply: Ignore them. There is nothing you can do to change others but yes there is so much you can do to change yourself.

Comment: Lord Krishna said that the one who is stable for heat and cold, love and hate are dear to Him.  :-)

Comment: The Lord does not need your defense. The Lord can stop it if so desired. Instead see Gita 12.18-19.

Comment: See [related discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/436/2995) on meta.

Answer (score 2):

In one word simply: Ignore them. There is nothing you can do to change others but yes there is so much you can do to change yourself.

Even if you worship him or not he was there, he will be there. Just like sun is not because of us, we are because of sun, else everywhere it will be darkness. If he can create/manifest everything than he can take care of such things, if and when needed.

Found this interesting [article](http://isha.sadhguru.org/blog/video/shiva-doesnt-need-your-devotion/) where a seeker asks Sadhguru about the importance of devotion, to which Sadhguru replies that being devoted is not about someone or something. Devotion is essentially an enduring sweetness of emotion, with which your body and mind will function at their best.

> So Shiva doesn’t need your devotion. It is just that if you carry
>   devotion in your heart… What is devotion, let’s look at this. On one
>   level devotion means a certain sweetness of your heart. It’s the best
>   way to be for any human being. If you do not carry this sweetness in
>   your heart you will be… life will do things to you and you will become
>   bitter. ‘So should I be devoted to Shiva?’ It doesn’t make any difference to Him but if you are a devotee – devotion is another kind of intelligence which simple intellect is unable to understand. The nature of a rudimentary intellect is, if you want to know anything we have dissect it. Yes? If you become interested in somebody, dissect them. Well you don’t do it physically because the law doesn’t permit it but you mentally dissect them, isn’t it?

You can take clue from our own history, where the mughals tried to change everything and convert everyone to follow their belief. This they did for more than 1500 years, after them came the britishers who again tried their best to make things happen their way for more than 200 years...but finally what happened? We are still here going strong!